# Why am I getting TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def tri_recursion(k):
    
    if (k > 0):
        result = k + tri_recursion(k - 1)
        print(result)
    else:
        result = 0
        return result
        
tri_recursion(6)
```

So when I shift the **'return result**' statement in line 7 to the left just under the **else** statement, I get the correct output. But when I keep the code as shown, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Why is that?

Comment: You aren't returning anything if your if statement is true, so it's implicitly returning None

Comment: btw you can achieve the same result by simply doing `sum(range(1, k+1))`

Answer (score 2):

Your recursive function is not returning anything when `k>0`, thus implicitly returning `None`

Try the below

```py
def tri_recursion(k):
    
    if (k > 0):
        result = k + tri_recursion(k - 1)
        print(result)
        return result
    else:
        result = 0
        return result
        
tri_recursion(6)
```